# Updating specific template in nested templates

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm trying to render nested view.
Say I have views BigView and SmallView

```
<script type="text/template" id="big-template">
  <% _.each(smallViews, function (smallView) { %>
    <%= smallView.$el.html() %>
  <% }); %>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="small-template">
  <div>
    <%- name %>
  </div>
</script>
```

I call render from the `bigView` and it renders everything fine, including its children `smallViews`.

How do I update (render) a `smallView` individually without rendering the `bigView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you don't call `view` methods from your template code. I would move the `render` code for a smallview to the bigview `render` method.

Which would look like the following:

```
var BigView = Backbone.View.extend({
   render:function() {
     for (var i=0;i<this.collection.length;i++) {
       var smallView = new SmallView({model:this.collection.at(i)});
       this.$el.append(smallView.render().el);
     }
     return this;
   }
});
```

Then your `SmallView`:

```
var SmallView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template:_.template($('#smallTemplate').html()),
  render:function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  },
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/AZObEVa/1/edit) that shows it in action with an event handler on `smallView` to re-render.

Comment: This works, however it seems strange to me keeping template logic in the View like this. Is this normal with Backbone? (I am new to BB).

Comment: I think it is, although I can't track down any evidence for or against the above approach. In my experience, templates are used to handle collection and model data, not for calling children view methods. This could be personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Just calling a properly defined `render` method of the `smallView` object should be enough. For example something like this.

```
// smallview file
var SmallView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // some other methods

    template: _.template($("#small-template").html()),


    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

// where you need to update the nested views
_.each(smallViews, function(smallView {
    smallView.render();
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will fix the issue with the inner view being able to update itself.